# How do you verify expected exception without using expected attribute in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

How do you verify expected exception without using expected attribute in TestNG

```
@Test(expectedException= ExceptionName.Class)
```

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you describe what you're trying to do, and why?

Comment: It is an interview question

Comment: You put the test code inside a `try{}` block and catch the exception. If the exception does occur, you pass. Otherwise, fail the test.